# How do I fine tune a model on a dataset with different classes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06208) the author fine tuned a COCO-pretrained model to PoseTrack Dataset. I want to do something similiar but I am not sure how to do that, since the number of classes (keyjoints) are not the same.

I thought about "disabling" certain classes but I am unsure how.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the last layer of the nn with the number of classes of your problem, and re train for your dataset (supposing it has the same input shape). You can use the pre trained weights of the previous layer so that the convergence will be faster and you will need less data

Comment: Hello this is indeed a matter of transfer learning but how do I handle that e.g. I have N number of Heatmaps because my model was trained on a dataset with N classes/keypoints of human poses but now I want to specify the predicted heatmaps specifically  to the correspondent keypoint on the new dataset with lets say N+5 classes. So that Heatmap X predict the head even on the new dataset?